# How to make base R double barplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made the following double marplot in base R, but would like to make the same graph in gig-lot if possible. How would I go about doing this?

```
data <- structure(list(
A= c(53, 39),
B = c(30, 36), 
 C = c(12, 19), 
D = c(5, 6)), 
.Names = c("Poor", "Fair", "Good", "Excellent"), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L))

attach(data)
print(data)
colors <- c("dodgerblue3","red3")
barplot(as.matrix(data), 
main="",
beside = T, ylab = "", ylim = range(0,65),  col=colors, border=F)

legend(5,60,  legend=c("Fox News", "CNN"), 
fill=colors, horiz = T, bty='n')
text(1.5, 55, "53%")
text(2.5, 41, "39%")
text(4.5, 32, "30%")
text(5.5, 38, "36%")
text(7.5, 14, "12%")
text(8.5, 21, "19%")
text(10.5, 7, "5%")
text(11.5, 8, "6%")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yet? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is how we could do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

data %>% 
  mutate(Group = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Group) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(name), y = value, fill = factor(Group))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue3","red3"), labels = c("Fox New", "CNN"))+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    legend.position = c(.95, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
    legend.direction="horizontal",
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(value, "%")),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    vjust = -0.5
  )
```

[image]